# encrypting large file taking too much time

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a file using aes 128. Everything works fine but it takes too much time to encrypt a file which is just 165 kb. I checked the whole internet and tried to use different tactics but the result is still same takes 1 minute to encrypt a 165kb file.

here is how I do the reading and encrypting

```
string keyStr = "abcdefghijklmnop";
byte key[16];
charToByte(key, keyStr.c_str());
//Key expansion  
word w[4 * (Nr + 1)];
KeyExpansion(key, w);

bitset<128> data;
byte plain[16];

//Encrypt the file s.csv to s.csv.enc  
ifstream in;
ofstream out;
in.open("s.csv", ios::binary);
out.open("s.csv.enc", ios::binary);

while (in.read((char*)&data, sizeof(data)))
{
    divideToByte(plain, data);
    encrypt(plain, w);
    data = mergeByte(plain);
    out.write((char*)&data, sizeof(data));
    data.reset();  //Set 0  
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

I took the code from:
https://programmer.group/c-implementation-of-aes-encryption-algorithms.html

any help is appreciated.

Comment: read file by 16 bytes and use ifstream this not serious

Comment: I already use ifstream and can you tell me how reading the file by 16 bytes going to make it work faster because i tried and it worked at the same speed as before

Comment: Checking the whole internet must have taken a long time in itself... Are you using compiler optimisations? Please show a [mre], what is `encrypt`, `divideToByte`, `mergeByte`?

Comment: All the functions are below in the link.

Comment: *I checked the whole internet and tried to use different tactics* -- Choosing someone's version of AES encryption, and then seeing that it doesn't work right, would make me search for something that may be used a little more by the C++ community.  Something like [Crypto++](https://cryptopp.com/)?  Also, you just don't want to take some anonymous code that supposedly encrypts a file, and use it for your own purposes.  The reason is that if the code is faulty, your "encrypted" files are either not encrypted, or easily unencrypted.  Use a trusted source, not some random code you found.

Comment: I meant the "using different tactics" to read the file. Yes you are right about using library, I used crypto++ at first but it didn't work for me or the example I was using might be outdated as I am not a pro at c++ I was only looking for the examples on the internet. But it would be great if you can provide example of crypto++ for file encryption

Comment: Well, you must have been using crypto++ incorrectly, as that library is used by thousands of C++ programmers.  Also, if you are not good at C++, then the last thing you want to do in terms of encryption is pick up some anonymous code from somewhere, instead of going and working with established libraries.  Yes, it is a learning experience to see what's behind AES encryption, but implementing it yourself, or going with something you have no idea who wrote it or their credentials, is not a safe thing to do, IMO.